# Compare degree of polynomial across the fixed and random effects

Tags: r, lme4

My data comprises lots of devices and each contains several measurement data points (Amplification against Voltage), so the data is grouped by Serial_number.
Then I have a lmer-model which is described in general as:

```
fit<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, **degree**) + (poly(Voltage, **degree**) | Serial_number), data = APD)
```

Now I would like to compare the different polyonimals each up to a degree of 3 for the fixed and random effects.

E.g.:

```
fit01<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, **0**) + (poly(Voltage, **1**) | Serial_number), data = APD)
fit11<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, **1**) + (poly(Voltage, **1**) | Serial_number), data = APD)
```

and so on. Do I have to check all possibilities (which are 16) or can I reduce it because of any smart assumptions? 
Finally I would have `anova(fit11,fit01)` and so on..
The problem is: When I now compare each time two different models than I really have to do a lot of comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit the models programmatically, then compare them all using AIC:

```
library(lme4)

combinations <- expand.grid(fixed = 1:3, random = 1:3)

models <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(combinations)), function(i) {
  f <- as.formula(paste(
    'mpg ~ poly(qsec,', combinations[i, 1], ') + (poly(qsec,', combinations[i, 2], ') | cyl)'
  ))
  lmer(f, mtcars)
})

names(models) <- apply(combinations, 1, paste, collapse = '_')
aics <- sapply(models, function(m) summary(m)$AIC)

result <- data.frame(model = names(models), AIC = aics)
result <- result[order(result$AIC), ]
result$dAIC <- result$AIC - result$AIC[1]

result
```

> ```
>          model      AIC      dAIC
> 3_3.REML   3_3 155.7776 0.0000000
> 3_2.REML   3_2 155.9683 0.1907229
> 3_1.REML   3_1 156.0175 0.2398943
> 2_3.REML   2_3 160.1618 4.3842105
> 2_2.REML   2_2 160.2372 4.4595903
> 2_1.REML   2_1 160.3215 4.5438645
> 1_3.REML   1_3 164.5201 8.7424622
> 1_2.REML   1_2 165.2802 9.5025476
> 1_1.REML   1_1 165.3264 9.5487699
> ```